# Flutter: implement material design Parent-child transitions (using SizeTransition?)

Tags: flutter, material-design, transition

Using Flutter, I'd like to create a transition like the one in the material design Parent-child transitions [here](https://material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html#hierarchical-transitions).

The transition should be from a child-widget in a SliverList to a new screen and vice-versa.
How can this be achieved?
Using a [PageRouteBuilder](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation) and a one of the [Animated Widgets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedWidget-class.html) maybe?